# Leaflet-Crashes when add too many name labels

Tags: leaflet

I'm not familiar with Leaflet nor a professional programmer, but need to see if Leaflet is ideal for some project and would like to ask for some help on the following:
By using Leaflet and then adding too many (20,000) markers (vector),  although the place names are not shown all at once, but in different zoom levels, the problem is in the beginning i.e when trying to load all those name labels; it crashes. Any help on that please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The (seemingly obvious) answer is: don't add so many labels. There are plugins like https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision that will help make things faster.